# Why use jQuery.fn to add a plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

So I'm under the impression that jQuery.fn is a shortcut for jQuery.prototype. But isn't a plugin a method of the jQuery **object**? Why would I want to add a method to the prototype? Wouldn't adding a method to the prototype give the method to objects made using the jQuery object as a constructor (as opposed to adding the method to the jQuery object itself)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is even a bit more complicated (or at least it seems so). Have a look at the [source code (jQuery 1.6.2)](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.6.2/src/core.js#L302):

When you call `jQuery(selector)` [you are actually calling](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.6.2/src/core.js#L6)

```
return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context, rootjQuery );
```

[In addition we have](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.6.2/src/core.js#L302) `jQuery.fn.init.prototype = jQuery.fn`.

So by extending `jQuery.fn`, we also extend `jQuery.fn.init.prototype`.

As every object we create with `new jQuery.fn.init` (by calling `jQuery()`) has a **reference** to the prototype, every object created in the past or in the future will have access to every method we assign to `jQuery.fn`.

I hope this clears up your confusion. If not, just ask :)

Answer (score -4):

jQuery has a documentation about this at [Plugins/Authoring](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring).

There are two different methods of adding a new plugin to the jQuery plugin:

```
(function( $ ){
  $.fn.myPlugin = function() {

    // Do your awesome plugin stuff here

  };
})( jQuery );
```

The `(function($))` is more safer than using the below one since an overwrite using something else except the `$` may cause the plugin to not work.

```
jQuery.fn.myPlugin = function() {

  // Do your awesome plugin stuff here

};
```

Comment: Yes I've read that, but nothing addressed my question. I perfectly understand how to do it, I just don't understand why we're supposed to do it that way. I'm probably just conceptually confused, but I'd like to know about what!

Comment: There are [many more](https://github.com/jquery-boilerplate/patterns/) opportunities to create a plugin